# How to set model to partial view in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-partialview

We have an MVC Partial view with model binding. Model has various properties including List. The partial view has a knockout data-bind looping thru the list of the model. The partial view has a dropdown.

On dropdown selected index changed event, we need to refresh the partial view model as the list in the model will be refreshed.

On invoking an ajax call on dropdown selection, controller method is hit.

When tried to render partial view in the controller method, the list property data is set with the complete page HTML.

I shall paste the code as soon as possible.

One way that I thought was to set the datatype of the result to be JSON and the controller method would return the model as JSON result. In the ajax call success part, use knockout mapping to map JSON to the viewmodel. I want to know if its possible to set the model of the partial view in the success method.

Kindly help me out. I need to refresh the partial view. Thanks in advance

Code:

Dropdown in Partialview:

```
<div id="divRequirement2" class="autocompletesection">

        @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                          .Name("cmbQuestionText")
                          .Placeholder("Start typing a Question...")
                          .DataTextField("QuestionText")
                          .DataValueField("AuditChecklistMasterDataId")
                          .DataSource(source =>
                          {
                              source.Read(read =>
                              {
                                  read.Action("GetRequirementDetails", "AuditDetails");
                              });
                           })
                           .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%;" })
                           .Filter("contains")
                           .MinLength(0)
                           .Height(370)
                           .Template("<span class=\"k-state-default\">#: data.QuestionText #</span>")

            .Events(e =>
            {
                e.Change("onInvReqChange");
            })
        )

            </div>
```

On ddl selection:

```
function onInvReqChange(e) {
    var combo = e.sender;

    //  var suppCombo = $('#suppliers');
    if (combo.value() && combo.select() === -1) {
        combo.value("");
        //selfSupplier.AuditViewModel.FactoryList(null);

        return;
    }
    var newVal = combo.value();
    //alert(newVal);
    selfSupplier.LoadInvQuestion(self.InvestigationViewModel);
}
```

Ajax call on ddl selection:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/[Controller]/[Method]',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        headers: headers,
        data: ko.mapping.toJSON(self.InvestigationViewModel),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(result.InvestigationList, {}, self.InvestigationViewModel.InvestigationList);
            ko.mapping.fromJS(result.LRDetailsList, {}, self.InvestigationViewModel.LRDetailsList);

            if (result == "") {
                $('#accordion1').html("<div class='row valSummBox' style='padding: 8px 0px 8px 8px;'><div id='noresult' class='errMsg'>No records found with given search criteria.</div></div>");
                $('#pop_up').css('display', 'none');
                ;
            }
            else {


                $("#accordion1").html(result);
                $("#cmbQuestionText").data("kendoComboBox").value($("#hdf_Id").val());
                $("#txtInvQuestion").val($("#hdf_AllegText").val());
                $('#pop_up').css('display', 'none');

                //$('#accordion1').load(url);
                //$("#accordionconfirm").hide();
            }
        },
        error: function (err) {
            $("input[type=button], input[type=submit]").removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#pop_up').css('display', 'none');
            $("#ermsg").html('<div class="errMsg">' + extractError(err) + '</div>').show();
            var scrollPos = $("#ermsg").first().offset().top;
            $(window).scrollTop(scrollPos);
            return;
        }
    });
```

In the action:

```
return PartialView("_SelectInvChecklist", objAuditDetails);
```

In the partial view:

```
<div id="accordion" class="customaccordion">
        <table class="tbl-unclosedNC table" id="tblSelectNC">
            <thead>

                <tr>
                    <th>Is this question linked to Checklist Questions?</th>
                    <th>Question ID</th>                        
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.InvestigationList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.LinkedToChecklist</td>
                        <td>@item.AuditRequirementTopic</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

In the code that is attached, we looped thru Knockout data-bind foreach logic. Since it didn't workout, where the "InvestigationList" of the model had complete page HTML, we used Razor looping.

One more thing that I noticed is that, this works fine on page load. But any action after the partial view has loaded and any action done like dropdown selection and data rebinding, the knockout bindings are all gone.

Comment: *I shall paste the code as soon as possible.* Should be the first thing you do.

Comment: Sure Erik. I've pasted the code. Kindly check and help me out

Comment: Hi. I got to know from my colleague that, once the Partial view is filled with data, the data shouldn't be refilled. We can use JSON to reset the knockout element bindings.. If we refill by PartialView("[view name]",data), then none of the bindings work, nor any button click